# C# Pass selection from listbox in form1 to textbox in form2

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listbox

I've got two forms and a custom class. I have populated a listbox in form1 using my custom class which holds several data types. I want to pass each of those values in the class located in the listbox to individual text boxes in form2. I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the individual values in each listbox instance of my class and then split them among the text boxes in form2. I thought I was on the right track by creating a property on form2 for my first textbox. I only have the one property set up right now because I wasn't sure it would work and was only testing. In form1 I was trying to set it up so I could access my class values from the selected item.

Form 1

```
    private void propertiesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmProperties editProperties = new frmProperties();
        DialogResult result = editProperties.ShowDialog();


        object employeeSelect = lstBoxEmployees.SelectedValue;
        editProperties.TextFirstName = Convert.ToString(employeeSelect);
    }
```

form 2

```
    public partial class frmProperties : Form
{

    public string TextFirstName
    {
        get { return txtFirstName.Text; }
        set { txtFirstName.Text = value; }
    }

    public frmProperties()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Comment: winform or wpf? and post only part of code!

Comment: winform. Sorry for the clutter

Comment: I've tried setting it up as lstBoxEmploees.SelectedItem(Myclass[0]) but it won't work. That gives an idea of what I'm trying to do I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void btnOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
      f2.ShowDialog();
   }

   public string ListBoxValue
   {
      get { return listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
   }
}
```

Form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   Form1 f1;
   public Form2(Form1 f1)
   {
       this.f1 = f1;
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       textBox1.Text = this.f1.ListBoxValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: This works but it messes with another part of my code and adds the whole listboxitem to one text box on form2. The part it messes with though is I already have a method set up to open form2 with text boxes blank so that I can fill them in and hit ok which then adds the values to an instance of my class and then adds that class to my listbox on form1. The code you posted would override that method I made and always populate form2 txtbox1 with whatever item is selected in form1's listbox everytime it's opened.

Comment: @user3594691 This is just a sample, you just have to modify according to your need